# Transition Maps and Inverse Function Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry

[image]
How after defining $\pi$ do the next lines follow? How does he say that $\tilde W$ is an open set and how does he write $\sigma^{-1}\circ\tilde{\sigma}$= $F^{-1}\circ\tilde F$ ? Here $\tilde F$=$\pi\circ\tilde{\sigma}$. How does he construct this $\tilde F$? How is $\tilde{{\sigma}^{-1}}$ defined on $\sigma(W)$? How the last equation on the page is formed?

Comment: As $\sigma$ is a homeomorphism, the image of an open set is open. Now using continuity of $\tilde\sigma$, you can see that $\tilde W $ is open.

Comment: Oh yes, I’ll delete the old one.

Comment: A thing that I’m not clear about is, how is $\tilde{{\sigma}^{-1}}$ defined on $\sigma(W)$? I mean in all of  $\sigma(W)$. $\sigma$ and $\tilde\sigma$ share the point $P$ but why should it be defined on the whole set? Also how does one get the last equation on the page?

Comment: You don't need $\tilde\sigma^{-1}$ to be defined on all of $\sigma(W)$ to talk about $\tilde\sigma^{-1}(\sigma(W))$. Recall that $\tilde\sigma^{-1}(\sigma(W))=\{(\tilde u,\tilde v)\in \tilde U\mid \tilde\sigma(\tilde u,\tilde v)\in \sigma(W)\}$.

Comment: Thanks, guess I’m confusing myself over notation. For instance if we talk about some $F(A)$ we talk about $F$ mapping all the points of $A$ then why not $F^{-1}(B)$, should be defined for all values in $B$ for some $B$? I’m also not sure how the following is obtained $\sigma^{-1}\circ\tilde{\sigma}$= $F^{-1}\circ\tilde F$ ? where $\tilde F$=$\pi\circ\tilde{\sigma}$.

Comment: Note that $\pi=F\circ \sigma^{-1}$ on $\sigma(W)$. So $$F^{-1}\circ\tilde F=F^{-1}\circ\pi\circ\tilde\sigma=F^{-1}\circ F\circ\sigma^{-1}\circ\tilde\sigma=\sigma^{-1}\circ\tilde\sigma.$$ I'm not entirely sure about the rigourness of the above "proof" though.

Comment: Shouldn’t the inverse function be defined on all points of its domain just like a function ought to be defined on all points it’s domain?

Comment: Also I’m not sure how the discussion about $\pi$ suddenly brought in $\tilde\sigma$